# Symfony ManyToMany relation add constraint without entity

Tags: doctrine

I have ManyToMany relation, without entity and I want add constraint for ManyToMany table, example for uniq fields, how it's done ?

My constrait example for entity

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="courses",
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="unique",
 *            columns={"courses_id", "courses_of_study_id"})
 *    }
 * )
 */
class Courses
```

But this is approcah for entity/ In my case I don't need create entity, just relation ManyToMany in both side. This relation create table in database with `courses_courses_of_study` with `courses_id` and `courses_of_study_id` and I want add to it `uniqueConstraints`

may entity

```
class Courses
{
use TraitTimestampable;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|CoursesOfStudy[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\CoursesOfStudy", inversedBy="courses", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $coursesOfStudy;
```

class CoursesOfStudy
{
    use TraitTimestampable;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection|Courses[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Courses", mappedBy="coursesOfStudy", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $courses;
```

I try added this `uniqueConstraints` to entity `Courses`, but after migration diff I have error

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                         
  There is no column with name 'courses_id' on table 'courses'.
```

when I try

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="courses")
 * @ORM\Table(name="courses_courses_of_study",
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @UniqueConstraint(name="unique",
 *            columns={"courses_id", "courses_of_study_id"})
 *    }
 * )
 */
class Courses
```

have error

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                                        
  The table with name 'project.courses_courses_of_study' already exists.
```

Comment: Remove the `uniqueConstraints`, it will be unique anyway because Doctrine will use both keys as the PRIMARY KEY in the many-to-many table. The correct way how to write many-to-many mapping can be found in [this](https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916) gist by Marco Pivetta.

Comment: hmmm, it's true ...